# Java: JFrame image only appears when maximizing window

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

I am trying to get an image to appear inside of my JFrame. However, this image only appears when I maximize the GUI window. My image is located inside my src folder. I was wondering if I am implementing JFrame incorrectly.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation
                (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("logo.png")));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You're adding two labels to container which is using `BorderLayout`, this could cause you issues.  Avoid `setSize` and `setBounds`, since you're using `pack` anyway.  If needed, you could use `setLocation` to position the frame.  Do ALL of that before calling `setVisible`.  If the image is within your `src` folder, this suggests that the image is "embedded" and you should be using `getResource` to generate a `URL` to the image and then loading it via `ImageIcon`

Comment: I removed setBounds and am using setLocation now, both before setVisible. The same problem is occurring. The image does not appear until I resize the window in some way... I'm thinking it has to do with how my image is embedded, like you said.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that you're adding two labels to the `BorderLayout` - the fact that the image is been loaded would suggest that it's not (yet) and issue with the image been embedded

Comment: How could I resolve this?

Comment: Minimise the code to start with - 1 label, 1 image.  Pack and show the window

Comment: @madprogrammer I updated my code in the original post. Also, [Before resizing window](https://imgur.com/a/3YhiEC0) and [After resizing window](https://imgur.com/a/qp4Ljha)

Answer (score 2):

Simple example.

The image is placed within `stof` package.  The example makes use of [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) to load the image.  The reason for this is two fold.

1. If something goes wrong, an exception is raised, so you can diagnose it
2. `ImageIO.read` won't return until the image is fully loaded.  This means that, unlike `ImageIcon`, you know the image is available for rendering once the call returns.  Just remember, if the image is large and you do this from within the event dispatching thread, you will cause the UI to "stall"

## Example

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Test.class.getResource("/stof/Background.png"));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```